# Winforms start position

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Is there a way to change Start position property (or other properties) for all the forms of a csharp project, not one by one ?
Thanks

(I mean can we change a property for all forms in the same project?)

Comment: Bind those properties to an Application-Setting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to do it Globally, then you could create your own Form where you will inherit the it from.

```
public partial class FormTemplate : Form
{
    public FormTemplate()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        // load properties from App settings probably
    }
}
```

And then inherit always the template instead the form

```
 public partial class Form2 : FormTemplate
    {
        public Form2() : base()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
```